# How to convert a dateformat from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, string, datetime, database-migration

I've been searching the internet for almost 6 hours now for the fastest solution to my problem.

I've got a SQL Server database where some of the tables have a DATETIME format for columns, but the values in these columns are in the following format:

DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM
eg.
18-12-2012 00:00

From my research MySQL only accepts the following format for its DATETIME values:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Now, I'm actually trying to make the conversion in the Scripts themselves, not the database.

basically I have over 250,000 records in multiple tables in SQL Server Script Format.
I've already changed all the syntax to MySQL except this part.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. URGENT.

thank you
This is the Table

```
CREATE TABLE Price(
  AirlineCode   char(2)     NOT NULL
, FlightNumber  varchar(6)  NOT NULL
, ClassCode     char(3)     NOT NULL
, TicketCode    char(1)     NOT NULL
, StartDate     DateTime    NOT NULL
, EndDate       DateTime    NOT NULL
, Price         decimal     NOT NULL
, PriceLeg1     decimal         NULL
, PriceLeg2     decimal         NULL

, PRIMARY KEY   ( 
                    AirlineCode, 
                    FlightNumber, 
                    ClassCode, 
                    TicketCode, 
                    StartDate 
                )
, FOREIGN KEY (AirlineCode) REFERENCES Airlines (AirlineCode)
, FOREIGN KEY (ClassCode)   REFERENCES TicketClass (ClassCode)
, FOREIGN KEY (TicketCode)  REFERENCES TicketType (TicketCode));
```

and this is a sample insertion:

```
INSERT INTO Price VALUES ( 'QF', 'QF67',   'ECO', 'E', '18-12-2012 00:00', '04-01-2013 00:00', 3427.82, 1636.14, 2045.20 );
```

Comment: Assuming there wouldn't be any conflicts, you could just use a regex to replace the dates with the MySQL format.  The seconds part is optional, so you could get away without appending 00.

Comment: You should be clear that the values in the `datetime` columns in SQL Server *don't* have a format - what you've shown is the default formatting that SSMS uses to *display* `datetime` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

Also, you may use [RegEx in SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx):

Find what: `{[0-9][0-9]}\-{[0-9][0-9]}\-{[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]} {[0-9][0-9]}\:{[0-9][0-9]}`

Replace with:`\3-\2-\1`

[image]

Comment: First of all I would like to say thank you to all for your efforts. This was the first question I've ever asked at StackOverflow.com and am really impressed by the level of support.

After a little bit more research, I remembered the good old toolkit of RegEx that I learnt last year. So I decided to put it in some good use.

in Notepad++ thanks to its Regex search capabilities, I managed to trace down every date value in my 250000 records and replace them with the required ones.

Comment: @Alisneaky: Also, you may use regex in SSMS.

Comment: I couldn't run anything on SQL Server management studio due to an installation problem. it has completely crashed on me....MySQL and Notepad++ was pretty much my only choices. but yeah thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert dates from a *known* format to a datetime value. Assuming that you have dates in `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` (all numbers 0 padded and hh:mm is a 24-hour time) you can use:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('18-12-2012 00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %k:%i')
-- 2012-12-18 00:00:00
```

You *can* use this function in your insert queries like so:

```
INSERT INTO Price VALUES (
'QF',
'QF67',
'ECO',
'E',
STR_TO_DATE('18-12-2012 00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %k:%i'),
STR_TO_DATE('04-01-2013 00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %k:%i'),
3427.82,
1636.14,
2045.20
);
```

## Edit

If editing your insert queries is not possible, you can let MySQL do all the conversion. Temporarily change the datatype of datetime columns to `VARCHAR` and import the data. Then add a temporary field e.g. `StartDate_Temp DATETIME` and run an update query:

```
UPDATE Price SET StartDate_Temp = STR_TO_DATE(StartDate, '%d-%m-%Y %k:%i')
```

Once you've verified that your data is OK, delete the temporary columns.

Comment: Ugh.  Infinitely more sensible than my answer.  Deleting mine.  +1

Comment: Ok thank you everyone for all your answers. I think the best one so far has been Salman's answer, since it is running in MySQL. I want to add the STR_TO_DATE function to my insert scripts, but there's over 250000 records. How can I search for 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM' values using Regex? I'm trying to do this via Notepad++. thanks

Comment: You need to improvise. See my edited answer in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to say thank you to all for your efforts. This was the first question I've ever asked at StackOverflow.com and am really impressed by the level of support.

After a little bit more research, I remembered the good old toolkit of RegEx that I learnt last year. So I decided to put it in some good use.

in Notepad++ thanks to its Regex search capabilities, I managed to trace down every date value in my 250000 records and replace them with the required ones.

([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])

this was the search I put through for the date format that I had, and then i swapped the year and the day values and added the seconds in there as well by having the following in the Replace with box:

\3-\2-\1 \4:00

Problem solved.